# Missing Roles Claims in the ASP.NET Core 2 and IdentityServer4

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, identityserver4, roles, claims-based-identity

I read https://leastprivilege.com/2017/11/15/missing-claims-in-the-asp-net-core-2-openid-connect-handler/ about mapping custom claims with this code line:

```
options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("website", "website");
```

I need to map roles and it works until I have just one role like "*User*".

```
options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("role", "role");
```

The problem is when I have more than one role like "*User*" and "*Superadmin*"
That code line throws an exception:

```
InvalidCastException: Cannot cast Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.
```

Anyone has any idea? Am i wrong something or it could be a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a discussion of this issue here:

https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1383

and in the same issue a potential solution to your problem with role:

https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1383#issuecomment-361505163 :

```
oidcOptions.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents()
{
  OnUserInformationReceived = async context =>
  {
    // IDS4 returns multiple claim values as JSON arrays, which break the authentication handler
    if (context.User.TryGetValue(JwtClaimTypes.Role, out JToken role))
    {
      var claims = new List<Claim>();
      if (role.Type != JTokenType.Array) {
        claims.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, (string)role));
      }
      else  {
        foreach (var r in role)
          claims.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, (string)r));
      }
      var id = context.Principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
      id.AddClaims(claims);
    }
  ...
}
```